# Function parameter error - Missing Argument Label Anomaly - SWIFT

Tags: xcode, function, swift

I have a strange issue (which I can overcome however I would like to get a proper understanding of my error).

I have a small random number generator function which I use often:

```
func ranNum(low: Int, high:Int) -> UInt32 {
var result = arc4random_uniform(UInt32((high+1)-low)) + low
return result
```

}

When I use this in XCode playgrounds it works just fine if I pass in something like:

```
ranNum(1, 10)
```

However, in a regular Swift file it generates the error message : Missing argument label 'hi:' in call. Now I can overcome this by calling the function this way:

```
ranNum(1, hi:10)
```

Apart from it just being a little harder to read, it just isn't making sense why it works in Playgrounds but also why it requires only the 2nd argument label and not both. Any help as to what I am not understandinh would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called [external parameter name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254), and by default:

- global functions: don't have implicit external names
- class/struct methods: external names are automatically defined for all parameters after the first
- initializers: external names are automatically defined for all parameters

If not explicitly specified, external names take the same name as the local parameter.

You can override that by prefixing a local parameter name with `_`. In your case:

```
func ranNum(low: Int, _ high:Int) -> UInt32 {
    ...
}
```

You mentioned that in playground calling the function works without any external parameter name - I may argue that:

- in playground you have that function as a global function
- in other tests, that function is a class/struct method

Am I right?

Comment: Thanks Antonio, solution found all in less than 10 minutes. I also appreciate both the explanation and the link the the documentation. Yes, you're assumption about my usage of it in the Playground was correct and hence the result as you noted. Appreciate your assistance, thanks :)